# Force configuration update on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm building a simple web app on Elastic Beanstalk (Dockerized Python/Flask). I had it running successfully on one AWS account and wanted to migrate it to a new AWS account, so I'm recreating the Beanstalk app on the AWS console and trying to deploy the same code via `eb deploy`.

I noticed that when pushing a configuration update, Beanstalk will attempt the change but then roll it back if the app fails to start with the new change. This is true for several different kind of changes, and I need to make multiple to get my app fully working (basically I'm just recreating the Beanstalk settings I already have on my other AWS account):

1. Need to set a few environment variables
2. Need to set up a new RDS instance
3. Need to deploy my code (the new application version has been uploaded, but the deployed application version is still the old "sample application" that it started with)

All 3 must be done before this app will fully start. However, whenever I try one of these on its own, Beanstalk will attempt the change, then notice that the app fails to startup (it throws an exception on startup) and then beanstalk rolls back the change. The config rollback occurs even though I have "Ignore Health Check: true" under the deployment settings. (I would think at the very least it let me force update #3 above but apparently not.)

So I'm basically stuck because I can't do all of them at once. It there a way to `--force` a configuration update, so that Beanstalk doesn't rollback no matter what happens?

My other thought was that I could potentially make all the edits at once to the JSON config, but I figured that there must be a way to force config changes so people can respond quickly in a crisis without these well-intentioned guardrails.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It could be easier to migrate to new EB env, rather then trying to modify the old one.

Comment: If you have access to the EB console, you can set up these when creating a new environment